# Any easily available ferromagentic material with $T_c$ in room temperature?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter

I want to experiment it in my house or office. I think it would be of great fun to see the transition in real life.

Answer (score 2):

Gadolinium is one candidate, and its $T_c$ is about 292 K.

**Ref**: Nigh, H. E., Legvold, S., & Spedding, F. H. (1963). Magnetization and electrical resistivity of gadolinium single crystals. *Physical Review*, 132(3), 1092.

Comment: Gadolinium has come down in price by about a factor of 100 since the Chinese started large scale rare-earth extraction.

Answer (score 2):

Gadolinium (Curie temperature - 292K (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature)), price: about 100 USD for 10g (http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/materials-science/material-science-products.html?TablePage=19297763 ), about 17 USD for 1.5 g at ebay (http://www.ebay.com/itm/GADOLINIUM-METAL-99-95-1-5g-in-ampoule-under-argon-/120173806351 ). Please research safety issues thoroughly (http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/263087?lang=en&region=US)

Comment: so it seems that such material is not so common, unlike iron. It is still not so cheap or so easy to obtain. It is still far away from everyday life.

Comment: @PKSer: Well, only you can decide if it suits your purpose. MnAs may be of interest as well (315K Curie point), but it is not cheap either.